# Where is ODATA EF for VWD 2010 Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4, ado.net, wcf-data-services, vwdexpress

I'm currently using VWD 2010 Express and am interested in exploring WCF REST in more detail, but I can't find "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" template or any information on how to install it. Is it correct that this is also referred to as ODATA Entity Framework? I'm wanting to create a WCF REST service using an SQL Express database and later, a MySQL database.

I've searched the online templates site, but not seeing it there either.

Btw, I'm mostly interested in VB templates for now.

Also, is it accurate to assume ODATA EF will work with MySQL databases? Are there alternate templates specifically for MySQL?

****UPDATE****
As per Ian Michael William's suggestion, I try to install WcfDataServices.exe. The install fails with this in the log file:

```
[0A34:08FC][2012-10-29T19:02:14]: Caching bundle from: 'C:\DOCUME~1\Bob\LOCALS~1\Temp\{e0328255-3f36-4c55-b959-379ddaeee93f}\.be\WcfDataServices.exe' to: 'C:\Documents and Settings\All Users.WINDOWS\Application Data\Package Cache\{e0328255-3f36-4c55-b959-379ddaeee93f}\WcfDataServices.exe'
[0A34:08FC][2012-10-29T19:02:15]: Registering bundle dependency provider: {e0328255-3f36-4c55-b959-379ddaeee93f}, version: 5.0.50831.0
[0A34:0BF8][2012-10-29T19:02:16]: Error 0x80092009: Failed to get authenticode certificate embedded in: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users.WINDOWS\Application Data\Package Cache\.unverified\wcf_dataservices
[0A34:0BF8][2012-10-29T19:02:16]: Error 0x80092009: Failed to verify signature of payload: wcf_dataservices
[0A34:0BF8][2012-10-29T19:02:16]: Failed to verify payload: wcf_dataservices at path: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users.WINDOWS\Application Data\Package Cache\.unverified\wcf_dataservices, error: 0x80092009. Deleting file.
[0A34:0BF8][2012-10-29T19:02:16]: Error 0x80092009: Failed to cache payload: wcf_dataservices
[03AC:043C][2012-10-29T19:02:16]: Failed to cache payload: wcf_dataservices from working path: C:\DOCUME~1\Bob\LOCALS~1\Temp\{e0328255-3f36-4c55-b959-379ddaeee93f}\wcf_dataservices, error: 0x80092009.
[03AC:043C][2012-10-29T19:02:16]: Application requested retry of payload: wcf_dataservices, encountered error: 0x80092009. Retrying...
[0A34:0BF8][2012-10-29T19:02:17]: Error 0x80092009: Failed to get authenticode certificate embedded in: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users.WINDOWS\Application Data\Package Cache\.unverified\wcf_dataservices
[0A34:0BF8][2012-10-29T19:02:17]: Error 0x80092009: Failed to verify signature of payload: wcf_dataservices
[0A34:0BF8][2012-10-29T19:02:17]: Failed to verify payload: wcf_dataservices at path: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users.WINDOWS\Application Data\Package Cache\.unverified\wcf_dataservices, error: 0x80092009. Deleting file.
[0A34:0BF8][2012-10-29T19:02:17]: Error 0x80092009: Failed to cache payload: wcf_dataservices
[03AC:043C][2012-10-29T19:02:17]: Failed to cache payload: wcf_dataservices from working path: C:\DOCUME~1\Bob\LOCALS~1\Temp\{e0328255-3f36-4c55-b959-379ddaeee93f}\wcf_dataservices, error: 0x80092009.
[03AC:043C][2012-10-29T19:02:17]: Application requested retry of payload: wcf_dataservices, encountered error: 0x80092009. Retrying...
[0A34:0BF8][2012-10-29T19:02:18]: Error 0x80092009: Failed to get authenticode certificate embedded in: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users.WINDOWS\Application Data\Package Cache\.unverified\wcf_dataservices
[0A34:0BF8][2012-10-29T19:02:18]: Error 0x80092009: Failed to verify signature of payload: wcf_dataservices
[0A34:0BF8][2012-10-29T19:02:18]: Failed to verify payload: wcf_dataservices at path: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users.WINDOWS\Application Data\Package Cache\.unverified\wcf_dataservices, error: 0x80092009. Deleting file.
[0A34:0BF8][2012-10-29T19:02:18]: Error 0x80092009: Failed to cache payload: wcf_dataservices
[03AC:043C][2012-10-29T19:02:18]: Failed to cache payload: wcf_dataservices from working path: C:\DOCUME~1\Bob\LOCALS~1\Temp\{e0328255-3f36-4c55-b959-379ddaeee93f}\wcf_dataservices, error: 0x80092009.
[03AC:043C][2012-10-29T19:02:18]: Error 0x80092009: Failed to cache packages.
[03AC:0E64][2012-10-29T19:02:18]: Error 0x80092009: Failed while waiting for cache thread to complete before executing.
[0A34:08FC][2012-10-29T19:02:18]: Removing bundle dependency provider: {e0328255-3f36-4c55-b959-379ddaeee93f}
[0A34:08FC][2012-10-29T19:02:18]: Removing cached bundle: {e0328255-3f36-4c55-b959-379ddaeee93f}, from path: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users.WINDOWS\Application Data\Package Cache\{e0328255-3f36-4c55-b959-379ddaeee93f}\
[03AC:0E64][2012-10-29T19:02:18]: Apply complete, result: 0x80092009 restart: No
```

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft stack for creating OData services is called "WCF Data Services", not to be confused with "WCF Services" or "WCF RIA Services". I believe VWD 2010 Express does have a template for creating a new "WCF Data Service".

We are strongly recommending that developers take a dependency on our NuGet packages, and I would similarly recommend that you use EF Code First to make your life a lot easier rather than dealing with "ADO.NET Entity Data Model".

I've been planning to blog this recently. I'll try to write up the blog post and get it posted by tonight if you can wait that long. (The examples will be in C#, but there won't be anything complex in there, so it should be easy to translate to VB.NET.)

I believe there are a few providers out there that will help EF work with MySQL. I have heard they are of varying quality but have not tried them myself. DevArt is consistently well-spoken-of in this space.

I'll update this answer when I get the blog post up.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I can definitely wait and will read your blog from top to bottom. I read another blog [Creating an OData API for StackOverflow including XML and JSON in 30 minutes](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingAnODataAPIForStackOverflowIncludingXMLAndJSONIn30Minutes.aspx) and another one (that's EXCELLENT) [A Guide to Designing and Building RESTful Web Services with WCF 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx) except that it uses WCF 3.5 and I'm not sure what changed in WCF 4.0. But I like what I'm seeing/reading and hungry to learn a lot more about this.

Comment: My hosting provider is GoDaddy and I'm limited on the number of MSSQL databases I can create. Only have 1 more left and I'm reserving it. I have quite a few MySQL databases left and so I would rather play on MySQL for now. I want to know all about using WCF REST with databases and returning XML, JSON, TEXT, HTML formatted responses. I'm also interested in RSS/ATOM feeds using WCF, as well as HMAC authentication in WCF services. I've created a couple of very simple WCF services as well as ASP.NET clients that consume them, but they're super simple and don't give me a feel for ADO.NET/ODATA.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the WCF Data Services 5.0 installer here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29306

...you should see both VB and C# item templates for VWD 2010 Express appear for 'web' projects appear.

Comment: Ian, I tried installing this earlier today but received an error. I wasn't sure if it was intended for my environment, so I gave up on it. I'm running XP w/SP3 and latest updates with VWD 2010 Express and the latest updates for it. I'm not aware of any problems anywhere else, but I get an error when installing the WcfDataServices.exe. I updated my question with the log file output.